# Bit Shifting and masking

Tags: c#

I have a question I am not great if it comes to low level programming so quick question I have a byte and each 2 bits in that byte mean something for example:

my byte is 204 so that should be 1100 1100 according to calculator so

```
bits 0..1 mean status of type 1
bits 3..2 mean status of type 2
bits 5..4 mean status of type 3
bits 7..6 mean status of type 6
```

So to check all values I use:

```
var state = 204
var firstState = (state >> 0) & 2
var secondState = (state  >> 2) & 2
var thirdState = (state >> 4) & 2
var fourthState = (state >> 6) & 2
```

But this looks odd I expext results
    firstState = 0
    secondState = 3
    thirdState = 0
    fourthState =3
but I am receiving 0,2,0,2. So what am I doing wrong?

Comment: should that be `& 3` ? or perhaps more clearly: `& 0b11` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to mask with 3 (11 in binary), not 2 (10 in binary):

```
var state = 204;
var firstState = (state >> 0) & 3;
var secondState = (state  >> 2) & 3;
var thirdState = (state >> 4) & 3;
var fourthState = (state >> 6) & 3;
```

When masking the operation is applied to the the bit in the corresponding location in each value, so:

```
And 
11001100  (204) 
00000011  (3)
-------- 
00000000  (0)
```

Whilst

```
And 
00110011  (51) 
00000011  (3)
-------- 
00000011  (3)
```

Comment: Ok it works, correct me if I am wrong mas is not length but value if I understand correctly?

Comment: @WojciechSzabowicz - sorry, I don't understand your comment

Comment: @WojciechSzabowicz Yes, when you mask or more properly do bit wise AND it is doing an AND on each bit so it's the value that matters.  It is not using the right side as the number of bits to keep

Comment: @WojciechSzabowicz - Ah, yes, it's the value of each bit that matters.

Comment: @WojciechSzabowicz 3 is a value not the length of bits to take. 3 in bits is 00000011. When you right-shift your state variable, the bits you are looking for is occupying the least-significant bits (000000xx), and when bitwise and ( & ) is applied, you get either 0, 1, 2 or 3.

Comment: @Sean sorry thought you were not going to write. Did not see before posting the comment either.